Determine if string is in Enum in VB.NET
I have an enum like this (in C#)
public enum Cars
{
    Toyota = 'T',
    Honda = 'H',
    Ford= 'F'
}

And a variable for myCar in VB
 Dim myCarValue As String = "H"

How can I check to see if myCarValue is one of the valid values in the Cars enum without comparing comparing against every value in the email? Is there a way to use Contains() to do this?

How do you have an Enum with strings as values?  Reference?

@dbasnett Char values not strings.  My enum is in C# and class is in VB.

Read about the Enum class and its members.

You can parse a string into an enum with Enum.TryParse

Not convinced the dupe target is correct, because the question is asking about a conversion of the value of the enum but the dupe target is focused on the name of the value.

@PanagiotisKanavos would that pick up the value equivalence?  I'm thinking not in this case.  I think using Enum.GetValues would be more effective.

@Rich - chars / strings aren't allowed.  Numeric types only.

@PanagiotisKanavos "H" is not a valid name, though.  It's a value.  The name is Honda.  (Strictly speaking, it's "H"C that's the value, not "H".)

@Craig you're right, I got confused.

You can use only numeric types in Enums. This code (originally VB) does simply not compile. You will get the compiler error:

Conversion from 'String' to 'integer' cannot occur in a constant expression

You must choose a different approach. I suggest using constants and a HashSet(Of String) to store them:
Public Module Cars
    Public Const Toyota = "T", Honda = "H", Ford = "F"

    Private ReadOnly _values As HashSet(Of String) = New HashSet(Of String) From {
        Toyota,
        Honda,
        Ford
    }

    Public Function Contains(carCode As String) As Boolean
        Return _values.Contains(carCode)
    End Function
End Module

Now you can do a check like:
Dim myCarValue As String = "H"
If Cars.Contains(myCarValue) Then

End If

You can also get a specific value with
Dim myCarValue As String = Cars.Toyota

This is very much how you would do it with an Enum.

In C# you would use a static class instead of a VB Module. Prefixing the member names with the Module name (as in Cars.Toyota) is optional in VB but mandatory in C# static classes.

If the values always consist of a single character, you could also declare the Enum as:
Enum Cars
    Totota = Asc("X")
    Honda = Asc("H")
    Fors = Asc("F")
End Enum

But then the check gets a bit ugly:
If System.Enum.IsDefined(Of Cars)(Asc(myCarValue)) Then

End If

Note that in C# single quotes are used to enclose System.Char (C#: char, VB: Char) literals who are considered to have a 16-bit numeric type (like System.Short) and are implicitly converted to an Integer in C#. This is why your C# code snippet works.
